# Force an animation block to finish

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

How can we force an animation block to finish before the time it takes to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Import QuartzCore framework
- For each view that is being animated:

  ```
  [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
  ```

Comment: Should I do this only for view, without subviews?